# codeigniter shows 403 when try to access another php file by clicking a link

Tags: codeigniter

[image]
this is my folder structure. I try to access from index.php to test.html through a link in this way.

```
<a href="application/views/pages/test.html">sss</a>
```

but it shows 403 error: You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

but iknow this is not a server error because links worked my local host well. this error from codeigniter. so how to fix this?.

Comment: What is the controller of test.html,  and what is your server host's document root?

Comment: You are NOT supposed to link file in views directory, but controller/method that is loading that file. If you are trying to follow static pages tutorial from docs, link should probably be `<a href="<?php echo base_url('pages/test');?>">sss</a>` (assuming you made test method there). Note that if you use file type other than php, you need to set it as well: `$this->load->view('pages/test.html');`.